# Why does display: inline-block; in IE have padding and margin that I can't clear?

Tags: css

The display: inline-block; property in IE seems have padding and margin that I can't clear no matter what I try and do. Has anyone else encountered this bug and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Could you please post a fiddle or some css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely because you have at least one space or linebreak between the `inline-block` element tags in your markup.

Linebreaks will be converted to a single space between `inline-block` elements. So the extra space you're seeing is not padding or margin, but an actual space character in the text of the containing element.

There are a few workarounds:

1. <s>Uglify</s> Change your markup to remove or reposition the linebreaks:

   ```
   <ul>
       <li>item</li>
       <li>item</li>
   </ul>
   <!-- becomes -->
   <ul>
       <li>item</li><li>item</li>
   </ul>
   <!-- or -->
   <ul>
       <li>item</li><li>
           item</li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. Use `float: left` or `float: right` to display your block elements inline instead of `inline-block`. Note that this will introduce other issues, like having to ensure that the containing element is [clearfixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best).
3. Set `word-spacing: -1em` on the containing element. Note that if your `inline-block` elements contain any text, and you don't want this text to have wonky word spacing, you'll need to override the inherited rule with `word-spacing: normal` on the inline elements. Demo: http://jsbin.com/ucivel/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

When using inline-block, be aware that whitespace you have used for formatting your markup will be rendered. This could be misinterpreted as persistent padding or margin.

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean by "whitespace"?